# Corona and conductor

Tags: electricity, electrical

We are decreasing corona by increasing conductor size and making it hollow but according to definition corona depends on level of voltage so eventhough you make it hollow and increase conductor size there won’t be any change in voltage transmitted so I didn’t get the fact how corona decreases by conductor size.

Some say it is because of potential gradient, others say skin effect

Skin effect - current flows around the conductor not at the centre so if we increase the hollowness of conductor Is it possible that more air will be prone to ionise than before?

Comment: Corona depends on the electric field strength, and humidity and dust; the field strength depends inversely on the radius.

Comment: Alternative to larger conductors:  high voltage dope.   It's a kind of paint/lacquer that insulates your conductors so you don't have as much corona discharge.

Answer (score 1):

Corona discharge isn't a matter of voltage but of field strength. The electrical field strength depends on voltage, but also on the area the charge is distributed on:

$$E = \frac{1}{A} \cdot \frac{Q}{\varepsilon_0}$$

A conductor cable or hollow conductor has a surface area of

$$A = 2\pi r \cdot l$$

as the inner surface is free from charge. For a bundled conductor, you have to run tests to get estimates on the equivalent surface area.

Comment: What if voltage levels are so high and you increase the conductor size eventhough you thought this will eliminate corona but instead it reduced corona and made more area surrounding conductor prone to corona. Will this action reduce corona loss?

Comment: I feel that making hollow will distribute corona effect but it would not eliminate it if voltage levels are high in conductor. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you wonder if the effect of the decreased electrical field strength and increased area are a zero trade-off, because they are reciprocal.

Comment: Will corona loss be completely eliminated by this process or it will be reduced

Comment: Corona losses are proportional to the square root of the quotient of the equivalent radius divided by the distance to other conductors (e.g. ground). It's a rather complicated formula of empirical knowledge. If you can read at least a bit German, it's explained e.g. here: https://books.google.de/books?id=P6CfBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA143#v=onepage&q&f=false